# LevelListDrawable with an empty case

Tags: android, xml, android-drawable, xml-drawable

Is it possible in Android to give to a LevelListDrawable an empty case? "Empty" is like "No Image". For instance, take a look at the LevelListDrawable here below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >        
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/face_1"
        android:maxLevel="1" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/face_2"
        android:maxLevel="2" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/face_3"
        android:maxLevel="3" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/face_4"
        android:maxLevel="4" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/face_5"
        android:maxLevel="5" />
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/face_6"
        android:maxLevel="6" />
</level-list>
```

It is a Dice with its 6 faces. I'd like to have an empty face too. A NULL case, or something like that.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >        
        <item
            android:drawable=""
            android:maxLevel="0" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_1"
            android:maxLevel="1" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_2"
            android:maxLevel="2" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_3"
            android:maxLevel="3" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_4"
            android:maxLevel="4" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_5"
            android:maxLevel="5" />
        <item
            android:drawable="@drawable/face_6"
            android:maxLevel="6" />
    </level-list>
```

Currently I simulate this behavior like this:

```
ImageView image = new ImageView(context);
image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dice));
image.setImageLevel(3);
if(somethingHappened){
    image.setImageDrawable(null);
}
```

But after that I have to call `image.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.dice));` another time instead of changing the image level. Thank you.

Comment: You should use a drawable for the null case for it to work, maybe add a transparent drawable instead of leaving the drawable field empty.

Comment: Yes, probably I'll do that way...

Answer (score 2):

`minLevel` is `0` by default, so if you want to exclude `face_1` from showing for `level=0` add it explicitly

```
<item
     android:drawable="@drawable/face_1"
     android:minLevel="1"
     android:maxLevel="1" />
```

The problem is that now `face_2` will be shown (because it's matching `[0, 2]`), but if you add `min` and `max` for all of the faces with the same values each, they'll play nicely.

See `android.graphics.drawable.LevelListDrawable.LevelListState#indexOfLevel` for more.

Alternatively I saw a magic value somewhere:

```
<item
    android:drawable="@null"
    android:maxLevel="0" />
```

But this will likely throw an NPE or exception from `LevelListDrawable#inflate`:

> <item> tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable